# Tableau Embed with jQuery and PHP passing parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tableau-api

I generally use Wordpress when building my internally facing dashboards with Tableau, but that will not work in this case so I am starting from scratch. I'm a novice with PHP and slightly above novice with jQuery, but I know my way around HTML. I need to pass an Okta javascript parameter into a Tableau embed. Below is my current code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var settings = {
     url: "https://harmelin.okta.com/api/v1/users/me",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {
       // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(err){
      //  alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
   }

   jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (success)  {
     console.log(success);
 var raw = success.profile.login;
 var email = raw.toLowerCase();
 var $login = email.replace(/@[^@]+$/, '');
jQuery("#write-data").append($login);

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php

// Tableau-provided functions for doing trusted authentication
require_once 'tableau_trusted.php';

?>

<div id="write-data"></div>
<?php
$user = 'jfedorowicz';
$server = 'dashboard1.harmelin.com';
$view = 'JoesPlayground/views/PTOStuff/Dashboard1?LCUsername=';
$theLogin = $login;

echo '<iframe src="';
echo get_trusted_url( $user,$server,$view$theLogin );
echo '" width="400" height="400"> </iframe>';
?>

</body>
```

Two problems:

1) What I am looking to do is pass $login (javascript variable) into $view. I 100% know that I did not do this right, but I cannot test because problem two.

2) I'm returning a 500 error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" which I assume is a Tableau error but I cannot figure it out.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: error one is very likely because of an inability to find the tableau_trusted.php file, the way you have that written it needs to be in the same folder as the file you're calling it from. Google turning on error reporting in PHP so you get an actual detailed error on the 500.

Comment: Thought that too but it is in that folder.

Comment: You definitely want to get error reporting turned on then, otherwise you (and we) are just flying blind on that error.

Comment: BTW, you are using Twig I assume? Otherwise those curly quote notations are going to throw PHP errors

Comment: Funny, I had the error in my console until I put on error reporting (Which worked correctly in my development website on the same server) but removed the 500 error. Where are the curly quotes?

Comment: $user = '{{MY USER}}'; << that is a Twig way of echoing out variables in PHP. That's what I meant sorry wrote quotes instead of braces, I was tired lol

Comment: I was just protecting my stuff, but nothing there can get me in trouble. I updated my code to the full version.

Comment: Ahh okay :) never mind me then lol.

Answer (score 0):

To generate authorization token you can use given code.
This code is working fine with all version upto 2018.3

/* PHP code to generate auth token */

```
$url = $dashboardURL . '/trusted';
$fields_string = "trusted_site=&username=" . $username;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now just pass this token with dashboard url in your `view/html` file.